# grails login verification

Tags: grails, spring-security

Really seem to be struggling with basic stuff in grails web-apps. Seems that no matter what I do I can't get the thing to behave the way I am expecting. Using the Spring Security Core plugin to add some security into the application but I can't force a redirect if the user has not logged in.

This is one of many issues I am facing but one at a time is best way forward. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package timetracker2

import grails.timesecurity.*

class TimeController {

  def springSecurityService

  def loginverify = {
    if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
    }
    else {
      render 'Please log in'
    }
  }

  static scaffold = Time
  ....
```

Answer (score 2):

With Spring Security, you typically don't check the logged-in state in code.

There are two ways to set up security requirements.

One is to set up security requirements for URLs. This is done via a interceptUrlMap in Config.groovy

The other is to use the Secured annotation on controller methods.
In this case, requiring the user to be logged in would look like:

```
class TimeController {

  @Secured("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")
  def someMethodRequiringLogin() {
  }

  @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
  def someMethodRequiringAdminRole() {
  }
}
```

For more info, see [Simplified Spring Security With Grails](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/)

Comment: Cool, will do some digging. Thank you for your help.

Comment: problem I have now unfortunately is that the controller class is largely using a scaffold and it really doesn't like being inside the secured method. "static is not allowed here". I did try using an interception map in my config but it was completely ignored by the application.

Comment: Please show us your code with the annotations and the full text of the compiler error or runtime error that you're getting

Comment: Sorry @GreyBeardedGeek code as below

`package timetracker2

import grails.timesecurity.*
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured;

class TimeController {
 
 
 def springSecurityService
 @Secured(["ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"])
 def validateUser(){
  
 
 static scaffold = true`

 Error Compilation error: startup failed:
C:\Users\Robert\Documents\workspace-ggts-3.1.0.RELEASE\TimeTracker2\grails-app\controllers\timetracker2\TimeController.groovy: 14: Modifier 'static' not allowed here.
 @ line 14, column 2.
    static scaffold = true
    ^
1 error

Comment: Looks like you have "static scaffold = true" inside the vlidateUser closure. It should be at the top of the class, outside of any methods or closures.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but then it ignores the @secured entry. 

I went back to your other suggestion though using the intercept URL Map in config.groovy, and while I still haven't got it to understand the difference between Admin an User roles at least I am prompted to log in.

Comment: I hope you're on gitHub under the same name because you clearly know your stuff and would love to see examples of your code.